# Can I merge 2 iTunes Store accounts?

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store

- I have 2 accounts on the iTunes store
- Each account is set to a different e-mail address, both of which I control
- One account is valid in the USA iTunes Store only
- One account is valid in the Dutch iTunes Store only

When I was just buying music and loading free TVShows this wasn't much of a problem. Now that I have iPhone Apps that regularly update, I find myself switching between these 2 accounts often. As you may know, this is not a user friendly process (log out - get sent to home page, nabigate - slow - etc).

Question: Is there a way to merge these two accounts into 1 account that has access to both the US and the Dutch iTunes store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer seems t be a big fat **No**. I have found messages of people that have contacted Apple with the same question (for exmaple, http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=903657), and they said they can't or won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the iTunes account policies this is not possible, as they do not support cross country accounts. This is validate via your credit card number, which is required to have a iTunes account.

Comment: I can help you with that. It is quite easy to have an iTunes account without a credit card. All you need is an iTunes Gift Certificate issued in the country of your choosing. These are easily bought on eBay (and delivered through e-mail). To be able to buy stuff, you will have toadd sufficient funds to your account using gift certificates.